# border image with pure css

Tags: html, css

This is the psd that i have to convert to html. I have to do it with pure css.

[image]

This image has a curvy border.I have to design this curved border with pure css not image. Is there any solution to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use Border-image property. Please see the location.

http://www.css3.info/preview/border-image/

Answer (score 2):

The only thing I can think of in terms of *pure* CSS, is an ugly hack like creating a div for every notch/tooth and giving it CSS3 rounder borders (which require [css3pie](http://css3pie.com/) for older versions of IE). Then you can just apply the colors you need.

I'm not sure if one could call this a solution though. A more practical approach would be to use border-image, but that has more issues with browser compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what you want, but if you can use CSS3, take a look at this link:

http://w3schools.com/css3/css3_borders.asp (`CSS3 Rounded Corners`)

Otherwise, check out one of the options in the following link:

http://w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp (`Border Style`)